# How to list only auto merged files in git

Tags: git, automerge

Is there any command to list only auto merged files in git after taking pull. Auto merging is not forcing us to watch code. Some time I needed to check explicitly to automerged files.

Git enlists changed files generally in three types in mix up. New files comes or old file deleted, auto merged and conflict.if git internally identifies automered files so I just thought there would be any command to list only auto merged files.by the way I want to get this list before the merge commit.

Comment: Do you want this list *before* or *after* the merge becomes a merge-commit?  I'd also note that if, e.g., you pick up a change to file F from your merged-in branch, and there is no change to F in your own branch, F is not an "auto merged file" (or at least I would not call it one) but a change in that file may cause issues depending on how your other files (also possibly not "auto merged") use something in F.  So I'm not really sure how useful such a list would be.

Comment: Git enlists changed files generally in three types in mix up. New files comes or old file deleted, auto merged and conflict.if git internally identifies automered files so I just thought there would be any command to list only auto merged files.by the way I want to get this list before the merge commit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For clarity in this answer, let's start with a few definitions and notes:

- To perform a merge, git must find the "merge base", which (very loosely) is "a commit at which the current branch and the to-be-merged branch share development history".
- You are doing a merge now and have either used `--no-commit` or gotten a merge conflict.  If the latter, you have not resolved these conflicts already.
- Thus, your work-tree has files ready to commit, but you have not actually made the commit.
- A merge, once committed, has two parent commits.  One is the commit that *was* the tip of the branch you were on just before you made the merge commit.  Since you have not yet made the merge commit, your current `HEAD` commit is the tip of this branch now.  So the phrase "the `HEAD` commit" below means "the tip of the branch before doing the merge".
- Meanwhile, we also need a short word or phrase for the commit from the to-be-merged-in branch (which will become the second parent).  I will call this the "inbound" commit.  (I have not seen this term elsewhere, I just made it up after going through some thesaurus entries.)

Based on your comment-reply, I believe you want to find files that have *any* change from the `HEAD` commit, i.e., those that have picked up any changes from the inbound commit, whether or not git has merged those without finding a conflict.

If this is correct, the answer is quite simple:

```
git diff --cached --name-only
```

will list them.  (This is a bit of a surprise since `git diff --cached` without `--name-only` does *not* show the unmerged files.)

Should you want only files git has (or thinks it has) successfully merged:

```
git status --porcelain | awk '/^M / { print $2 }'
```

will list those.  (Leave out the `awk`, and optionally use `-s` or `--short` instead of `--porcelain`, to see the output from `git status`.  In this case we look for files whose state is "merged, ready to commit".  Files with merge conflicts will be in `M` state.)

You may also want to compare files to their merge-base versions.  This is not too difficult *except* in the (somewhat rare) case of multiple merge-bases.  I will leave these details out of this answer, though.